# How to use a loader script with PHP app?

Tags: php, .htaccess, loader

So I have designed a PHP application that uses an oAuth2 API integration to create a unique interface for a CRM. App is working great on my server, and am ready to offer it to my clients.

**My initial idea for expanding this was to create a unique subdomain for each of them on my server, create a new database, and install my application onto that subdomain.** My application only has one hard-coded file with the database login details, the rest is stored on a database.

*The problem I see with this is it is inefficient.* I am essentially going be putting in the same files in many directories, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Plus updating it would be annoying.

*Since everything is being hosted by me, it was suggested that I create a core folder with all of the files.* Then I could use a loader script to read the database settings, and then use relative paths to access the core folder.

**My issue is how would this work?** Suppose my core domain is https://core.mydomain.com and my customer url is https://cus.mydomain.com. Customer logins through their url. Now a customer wants to access https://cus.mydomain.com/person.php. How would I make that work, considering that file is not located there *(since it is in the core folder)*? Would this require using custom htaccess?

**If my current idea is wrong, what approach would you suggest?** I am not married to this approach, and am looking for an efficient way of updating and managing the app. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a symbolic link?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)

You can create a folder with all your static files in `/var/www/core/` and create a symbolic link in each customers folder.

```
ln -s /var/www/core /var/www/customer001/core/
```

this way all modifications in /var/www/core/ will be available to all customers

Comment: Sorry for the very slow reply, I didn't get notified when this came through. So I have one hard-coded file for customer info, and the rest would be in the core folder. Suppose that file is called hardcode.php and located in https://cus.mydomain.com/hardcode.php. So if used the above symbolic link, wouldn't it then redirect to https://core.mydomain.com/hardcode.php? How would I avoid that, so it would still access the hardcode.php locally (in cus subdomain) but all other files and directories in core subdomain?